# Why $Null validation failed in powershell function?

Tags: powershell, validation

team!

I have validation script for parameter $Data.
It fail when it get $null.

whats wrong?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(  HelpMessage = "PsObject data." )]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [ValidateScript({
            if ( ( $_ -eq $null ) -or ( $_ -eq '' ) ){
                $true
            }
            else {
                (( !( $_.GetType().IsValueType ) ) -and ( $_ -isnot [string] ))
            }
        })]        
        $Data,
...

$UserObject = Show-ColoredTable -Data $null -View 'SamAccountName', 'Name', 'DistinguishedName', 'Enabled'  -Title "AD User list" -SelectMessage "Select AD user(s) to disable VPN access: " -AddRowNumbers -AddNewLine -SelectField "SamAccountName"
```

Comment: Your validation logic doesn't make too much sense - you want to `[AllowEmptyString]` but fail on input validation whenever any `[string]` is passed?

Comment: You are right. But the result is the same.

Comment: Also: If you parameter (`$Data`) is _untyped_ (implies `[object]`), you don't _need_ `[AllowNull()]`, `[AllowEmptyCollection()]`, and `[AllowEmptyString()]` - it'll work the same without them.

Comment: Corrected it. The same validation error. $data can be [string] or [psobject] or something else. It else, doesnt work without [AllowNull()], [AllowEmptyCollection()], [AllowEmptyString()].

Comment: Yes - my comment was just an aside. The real problem is explained in Mathias' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most validation attributes are incompatible with `[AllowNull()]` because the first thing they all check - before your custom validation is invoked - is whether the input object is `$null` or not.

Move the validation logic inside the function body:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(  HelpMessage = "PsObject data." )]
    [AllowNull()]
    [AllowEmptyCollection()]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    $Data
)

# validate $Data here before the rest of the script/command
```

Comment: It`s a good idea. My aim, to validate this, inside validatescript block.

Comment: @Alex, it's not just a good idea, it's _your only option_ as of PowerShell 7.2, because, as the answer implies, the use of `[ValidateScript()]` alone - irrespective of the content of the script - unexpectedly prevents passing `$null`. This is arguably a _bug_, which was reported in May 2020 in [GitHub issue #12557](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12557). A succinct repro: `& { param([ValidateScript({ $true })] $Foo) } -Foo $null`

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen, I think, and for Powershell 7.1 and 5.1 also.

Comment: Indeed, this behavior [stretches back to at least 5.1](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/source-depot/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Attributes.cs#L1296-L1302)